# How to update MongoDB document only when data changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am building the back-end of a CRUD application. I currently have a POST route setup for `/diagrams/update:id`, where I can override a MongoDB document with the body text that I send in via Postman.

I can successfully update the document, but when I try to update just one data inside a document, everything else gets deleted.

I want my code to 1) detect if what I am trying to change is different from the data in the database, 2) only if it is different, update the record, 3) if there is no change, do not update and keep the current data in the database.

I tried to do something like

```
if (diagram.name !== req.body.name) {
diagram.name = req.body.name}
```

but that would mean I have to write that logic for every single change.

server.js

```
router.route('/diagrams/update/:id').post((req, res)=> {
  mySchema.findById(req.params.id, (err, diagram) => {
    if (!diagram)
      return next(new Error('Could not load doc!'))
    else {

// I tried something like
// if (diagram.name !== req.body.name) {
// diagram.name = req.body.name}
// but that only works one at a time

      diagram.name = req.body.name;
      diagram.creator = req.body.creator;
      diagram.customer = req.body.customer;

      diagram.save().then( diagram => {
        res.json('Update done!')
      }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send('Update faileddddd')
      })
    }
  })
})
```

MySchema.js

```
const mongoose = require( 'mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let mySchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String
    },
    creator: {
        type: String
    },
    customer: {
        type: String
    }
}, {collection: `fivo`})
```

Comment: Are you passing in a `name`, `creator`, and `customer` on every request?  My first thought of why this is removing data would be if you are not, or you are passing them in as a blank or null value.

Comment: `Object.assign(diagram, req.body)`

Comment: When you pass in just `name`, only the name updates. When you pass in `name`, `creator`, and `customer`, yes, it gets passed as a blank and updates to the blank value. Later on when I build the front end interface, I need the user to be able to edit each field only if something changed. Does that mean I still have to pass in `name`, `creator`, and `customer` every single time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Just pass all the values to be updated in a object.

```
let update = async (userId, properties) => {
  let user = await Users.findOne({ _id: userId });

  // Update all properties.
  for(property in properties) {
    user[property] = properties[property];
  }

  user = await user.save();
  return user;
}
```